# How can I delete Azure DevOps old build pipelines and there leases with Power Shell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-pipelines, devops

Hello Azure DevOps Specialists

I do have in Azure DevOps some old build pipelines, that I want to delete using Power Shell.
I wrote a little power shell script to get the build definitions first and then get the build id, name, etc. Before I can delete a definition, the retained releases must be deleted.
The program code is prepared, but the API requires an ownerId or userId or Minimal Retention Leases. And that is my challenge!

I read the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/leases?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0 and the code behind (hosted on GitHub https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-node-api/blob/470f9ca7bdfccd87e1c1fdea8023b8c3d2b1047a/api/interfaces/BuildInterfaces.ts#L2006), but I have no idea what the ownerId or userId is or how I can find it.

```html
$personalToken = "AzureDevOpsPersonalToken"
$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($personalToken)"))
$header = @{authorization = "Basic $token"}

$organization = "myOrga"
$project = "myProj"

$pipelineName = Read-Host "Please enter pipeline to delete"

#all build definitions
$url = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/build/definitions?api-version=6.0-preview.7"
$builddefinitions = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $header

$builddefinitions.value | Sort-Object id|ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host $_.id $_.name $_.queueStatus
 
    if ( $_.name -ne $pipelineName ) {
        return;
    }

    #all builds for a definition
    $url = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/build/builds?definitions=" + $_.id + "&api-version=6.0-preview.5"
    $builds = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $header
 
    $builds.value | Sort-Object id|ForEach-Object {
        #report on retain status
        Write-Host " BuildId:" $_.id " retainedByRelease:" $_.retainedByRelease

        # ownerId UNKNOWN - where is this come from?
        $url = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/build/retention/leases?ownerId=&api-version=6.0-preview.1"
        $leases = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $header

        Write-Host $leases

        #$url = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/build/retention/leases?ids=" + $_.id + "&api-version=6.0-preview.1"
        #Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $header
        
        #Write-Host " BuildId:" $_.id " removed retentions"
        #
        #$url = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/build/builds/" + $_.id + "?api-version=6.0-preview.1"
        #Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method DELETE -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $header
        #Write-Host " BuildId:" $_.id " deleted"
    }

    #$url = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/build/definitions/" + $_.id + "?api-version=6.0-preview.1"
    #Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Delete -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $header
    #
    #Write-Host " Pipeline:" $pipelineName " (" $_.id ") deleted"


    Write-Host
}
```

Can you help me?
Thank you in advance
Tino

Answer (score 23):

Stuff in Azure DevOps Portal changes frequently. In February 2022 I composed my own script out of several Stackoverflow posts to remove old Build Pipelines, their Builds and their Leases.

```
#Azure DevOps Personal Access Token
# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=Windows

$personalAccessToken = "<Enter your personal access token here>"
$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($personalAccessToken)"))
$header = @{authorization = "Basic $token"}

$organization = "<Enter your Azure DevOps Organization here>"
$project = "<Enter your Project Name here>"

$pipelineName = "<Enter the Build Pipeline Definition Name to be deleted here>"

#Get all build definitions
# API: GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/definitions/{definitionId}?api-version=6.0
$url = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/build/definitions?api-version=6.0"
$allBuildDefinitions = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $header

$allBuildDefinitions.value | Where-Object {$_.name -eq $pipelineName} | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host $_.id $_.name $_.queueStatus
 
    # For debugging reasons, just to be sure that we don't delete the wrong build pipeline
    if ( $_.name -ne $pipelineName ) {
        return;
    }

    #Get all Builds for a Definition
    # API: GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds?definitions={definitions}&queues={queues}&buildNumber={buildNumber}&minTime={minTime}&maxTime={maxTime}&requestedFor={requestedFor}&reasonFilter={reasonFilter}&statusFilter={statusFilter}&resultFilter={resultFilter}&tagFilters={tagFilters}&properties={properties}&$top={$top}&continuationToken={continuationToken}&maxBuildsPerDefinition={maxBuildsPerDefinition}&deletedFilter={deletedFilter}&queryOrder={queryOrder}&branchName={branchName}&buildIds={buildIds}&repositoryId={repositoryId}&repositoryType={repositoryType}&api-version=6.0
    $url = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/build/builds?definitions=" + $_.id + "&api-version=6.0"
    $allBuildsOfDefinition = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $header
 
    #Process each Build of Definition
    $allBuildsOfDefinition.value | Where-Object {$_.retainedByRelease -eq "True"} | Sort-Object id | ForEach-Object {
        #Report on retain status
        Write-Host "Build Id:" $_.id " retainedByRelease:" $_.retainedByRelease

        #Get all Retention Leases for this Build
        # API: GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/leases?api-version=7.1-preview.1
        $url = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/build/builds/" + $_.id + "/leases?api-version=7.1-preview.1"
        $allLeasesOfBuild = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $header

        #Delete each Lease of Build
        $allLeasesOfBuild.value | ForEach-Object {
            #Delete Lease
            # API: DELETE https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/retention/leases?ids={ids}&api-version=7.1-preview.2
            $url = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/build/retention/leases?ids=" + $_.leaseId + "&api-version=7.1-preview.2"
            Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Delete -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $header

            #Report on Lease deleted
            Write-Host "Lease Id:" $_.leaseId " deleted"
        }

        #Delete Build
        # API: DELETE https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}?api-version=7.1-preview.7
        $url = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/build/builds/" + $_.id + "?api-version=7.1-preview.7"
        Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Delete -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $header

        #Report on Build deleted
        Write-Host "Build Id:" $_.id " deleted"
    }

    #Delete the Build Definition
    # API: DELETE https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/definitions/{definitionId}?api-version=6.0
    $url = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/build/definitions/" + $_.id + "?api-version=6.0"
    Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Delete -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $header
    
    Write-Host "Build Definition:" $pipelineName " (" $_.id ") deleted"
}
    
Write-Host "Habe fertig!"
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Excellent work.  Azure Devops seems to have this habit of deprecating things that you have no way to go back and easily change.  In our case it was policies that no longer exist and couldn't be removed, but were preventing me from removing old build definitions.  This saved me untold hours of manually deleting pipeline runs.  Many thanks!

Comment: Great work! This is sweet... Thanks a lot for all the time you saved me!

Answer (score 2):

Meanwhile I found am how-to from an unknown person on https://tenbulls.co.uk/2020/03/25/delete-old-build-definitions-in-azure-devops/ .

The trick is to **patch** the retainedByRelease value with **retainedByRelease=false**.

```html
$url = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/build/builds/" + $_.id + "?api-version=6.0-preview.5"
 
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Patch -Body (ConvertTo-Json @{"retainedByRelease"="false"}) -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $header
```

```html
$personalToken = "AzureDevOpsPersonalToken"
$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($personalToken)"))
$header = @{authorization = "Basic $token"}

$organization = "myOrga"
$project = "myProj"

$pipelineName = Read-Host "Please enter pipeline to delete"

#all build definitions
$url = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/build/definitions?api-version=6.0-preview.7"
$builddefinitions = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $header

$builddefinitions.value | Sort-Object id|ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host $_.id $_.name $_.queueStatus
 
    if ( $_.name -ne $pipelineName ) {
        return;
    }

    #all builds for a definition
    $url = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/build/builds?definitions=" + $_.id + "&api-version=6.0-preview.5"
    $builds = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $header
 
    $builds.value | where {$_.retainedByRelease -eq "True"} | Sort-Object id|ForEach-Object {
        #report on retain status
        Write-Host " BuildId:" $_.id " retainedByRelease:" $_.retainedByRelease

        #api call for a build
        $url = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/build/builds/" + $_.id + "?api-version=6.0-preview.5"
 
        Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Patch -Body (ConvertTo-Json @{"retainedByRelease"="false"}) -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $header
    }

    $url = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/build/definitions/" + $_.id + "?api-version=6.0-preview.1"
    Write-Host $url
    Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Delete -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $header
    
    Write-Host " Pipeline:" $pipelineName " (" $_.id ") deleted"
}
    
Write-Host "done"
```

Comment: That's great you fixed it. You can accept above answer of yours

Comment: this doesn't seem to work for me.  I've run that code exactly (with my org details) but i still get the error: Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.HttpResponseException: Response status code does not indicate success: 405 (Method Not Allowed).
   at System.Management.Automation.MshCommandRuntime.ThrowTerminatingError(ErrorRecord errorRecord).  If i change the version of the api in the last url for the last call to api-version=6.0-preview.5, i then get: TF900561: The following build cannot be | deleted because there is a retention lease on it

Comment: Something to do with the branch policy i think.  Is there any way to delete the branch policies/release management policies and then retention policies at the same time?  Very frustrating. It seems to depend on when the build was run (and whether there were release template attached to the build in the past

Answer (score 1):

Just an FYI, I ran the above script and was still having problems with it not allowing me to delete all retained builds. Instead I had to query leases for the current build and delete them individually, then I was able to delete the build. My modified loop from the other answer is below.

```
    $builds.value | where {$_.retainedByRelease -eq "True"} | Sort-Object id|ForEach-Object {
        #report on retain status
        Write-Host " BuildId:" $_.id " retainedByRelease:" $_.retainedByRelease

        #api call for a build
        $url = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/build/builds/" + $_.id + "?api-version=6.1-preview.7"

        #Get All leases for the current build

        $leaseurl = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/build/builds/" + $_.id + "/leases?api-version=6.1-preview.1"
        $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $leaseurl -Method Get -Headers $header
         
        if ($result.count -gt 0){
            $result.value | ForEach-Object {
                $deleteLeaseUrl =  "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/build/retention/leases?ids=" + $_.leaseId + "&api-version=6.1-preview.2"
                Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $deleteLeaseUrl -Method DELETE -Body "{}"  -ContentType "application/json"  -Headers $header
            }
        }
     

        Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -Headers $header
        Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method DELETE  -Headers $header
    }
```

Comment: I had the same issue, thanks. In my case there were too many builds, so the API was not updating the flag on all builds. Removing the builds using your script fixed the issue.